# Como puedo comparar al momento de indexar un objeto en un arbol generico

Tags: c++

Pero, me he quedado estancando en el filtrado y sort. Lo que hice por ahora es indexar mi clase Archivo ( tiene nombre,tamaño y ruta) al arbol, pero lo que piden es hacer un sort entre estos archivos (por nombre ascendente y/o descendente) y ademas filtrar los archivos. Mi clase arbol

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Archivo.hpp"
#include "Nodo.hpp"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template<class T>
class ArbolAVL {
private:
    Node<T>*raiz;
    void(*procesar)(T);
    int cant;

    void _Insertar(Node<T>*&nodo, T  e) {
    if (nodo == nullptr) {
        nodo = new Node<T>(e);

    }
    else if (e >nodo->key)_Insertar(nodo->right, e);
    else if (e < nodo->key)_Insertar(nodo->left, e);
    Balance(nodo);
}

    void _InOrden(Node<T>*& nodo) {
        if (nodo == nullptr)return;
        _InOrden(nodo->left);
        procesar(nodo->key);
        _InOrden(nodo->right);
    }



public:
    ArbolAVL(void(*lol)(T)) {
        procesar = lol;
        raiz = nullptr;

    }
    void Insertar(T e) {
        _Insertar(raiz, e);
    }
    void InOrden() {
        _InOrden(raiz);
    }
};
```

Y mi clase archivo

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace System;
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
class Archivo {
public:
    string path;
    string nombre;
    string extension;
    int fsi;


public:
    Archivo(string path) {
        this->path = path;
        String^ str2 = gcnew String(path.c_str());
        nombre = getFileName(path);
        extension = getExtension(path);
        fsi = f
}
```

Y finalmente mi clase controlador

```
void Print(Archivo * e) {
    cout << e->nombre << " " << endl;
}

class Controlador {
    ArbolAVL<Archivo*>*tree;

public:
    Controlador() {
        tree = new ArbolAVL<Archivo*>(Print);

        }
    void BuscarArchivos() {
        system("cls");
        string path;
        cout << "Ingrese la ruta: ";
        cin >> path;

        Archivo * arc2;
        string test;
        for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
            test = entry.path().string();
            arc2 = new Archivo(test);
            tree->Insertar(arc2);

        }

    }
    void ImprimirArchivos() {

        tree->InOrden();
    }
```

He visto en algunas partes del foro que utilizan operadores en la clase para poder comparar al momento de insertar pero no sé por qué no me cambiaba nada solamente comparaba los digitos de la memoria del archivo insertado. Agradecería mucho su respuesta.

Comment: Muy fan de que alguien use la extensión `hpp` <3

Comment: Por otro lado: No entiendo la pregunta ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente?

Comment: Bueno, por donde empiezo. Primer lugar, no puedo encontrar un nodo en específico (con atributos definidos por el usuario) y por último cómo puedo ordenar por atributos el árbol si es un Árbol<Archivo*>

Comment: ¿Cuál va a ser el criterio de ordenamiento de tu árbol?